# linksys wap54g default wpa wireless key?

Tags: networking

I wrongly pressed the push button in linksys wap54g web administration. 
Then it restarted and stated that it's protected with WPA while I first configured it as WEP. 
So, my old key didn't work. What should I do? Plugin with wire cable to reconfigure it? - which is the only way? coz it was embedded in ceiling.

I found no solutions in product manual and google.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using the old key for WPA?

Answer (score 1):

There generally isn't a default WPA or WEP key; As a general rule it's not a good idea to configure anything related to wireless settings while connected over the same wireless.

As to fixing it, you're best bet is to connect to it with a cable and log in that way; If it's in the ceiling, then simply find a way to get on the same network as it - you should have a switch or router somewhere else if this is just an access point. Once connected, you need only the AP's IP address to connect to it's webconfig and change the Wifi encryption and key.

Comment: yes, I think so but I wonder why it becomes WPA mode automatically and I guess there must be key for it.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. The other linksys products I've used (mostly wireless routers, but I've not used one of their WAP devices before) wouldn't switch to to WPA unless I set it to WPA, give it a key, and click save - since you did none of this, I'm assuming that something, somewhere caused it to get confused. (When I switch my routers to WPA, there is no default key in the box; it's just "blank", waiting for a key. However, a blank/null key is not valid)